# Zookeeper not starting, nohup error

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, nohup

I have Downloaded zookeeper-3.4.5.tar.gz and after extracting it I wrote conf/zoo.cfg as

```
tickTime=2000

dataDir=/var/zookeeper

clientPort=2181
```

Now I tried to start zookeeper by bin/zkServer.sh start
it gives

```
mohit@mohit:~/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin$ sudo sh zkServer.sh start
[sudo] password for mohit: 
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /home/mohit/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
```

But

```
$ echo ruok | nc localhost 2181
```

is not giving any output.

I checked zookeeper.out, it gives

```
mohit@mohit:~/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin$ cat zookeeper.out 
nohup: failed to run command ‘java’: No such file or directory
mohit@mohit:~/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin$
```

But my JAVA variables are set, I am not getting why this error is coming?

```
mohit@mohit:~/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin$ echo $JAVA_HOME 
/usr/lib/jdk
mohit@mohit:~/zookeeper-3.4.5/bin$ echo $PATH 
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jdk/bin
```

please help.Thanks in advance:)

Comment: What is the result of `java -version`?

Comment: Also, `sudo sh` is going to replace your environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ElliottFrisch , yes sudo was changing my environment.

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

Sudo was changing the environment.

So I set the environment variables for root.

Thanks to Elliott Frisch.

Answer (score 0):

simply add following lines to beginning of zkServer.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jdk
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

btw1: you can make the script executable by:

```
 sudo chmod a+x zkServer.sh
```

I suppose that first line is: #!/bin/bash so you can start it by:

```
sudo zkServer.sh start
```

BTW2: it is bad practice to run java code as root if it is not rally necessary.
good luck.

BTW3: are you sure that you jdk is directly in folder :/usr/jib/jdk and not in some subfolder? You can validate it  by running the exports and then try: java -version