# zookeeper Starting error :'JAVA_HOME error in zookeeper.out'

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

When I do

```
bin/zkServer.sh start    #It shows it has started

ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /data/sparkHA/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
```

Afetr few second when i check status, I got

```
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /data/sparkHA/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Error contacting service. It is probably not running.
```

My zookeeper.out says

```
nohup: failed to run command â/usr/bin/java/bin/javaâ: Not a directory
```

But my JAVA_HOME in bashrc is usr/bin/java, How come one extra /bin/java is added , that results in an invalid directory.

Also echo $JAVA_HOME outputs

```
/usr/bin/java
```

How to approach this error. Please Help. Thanks.

Also tried setting JAVA_HOME in zkServer.sh also by following [Zookeeper not starting, nohup error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791846/zookeeper-not-starting-nohup-error) but getting same error.

Comment: The contents of `/usr/bin` are normally executable files, not directories (that's not completely true, but for this purpose sufficient). It's possible that you *have* installed your JDK/JRE there; to verify, `ls -l /usr/bin/java` -- if it's a directory, update this question with the output from that command. If it's a file, then *Maxim Dobryakov* has the correct answer and you'll have to find your actual JDK installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JAVA_HOME` point to `/usr/bin/java` file but it should point to root directory of your JDK. For example for me this is:

```
➜  ~ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home
➜  ~ ll $JAVA_HOME
total 52064
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel   3.2K Oct  1 09:00 COPYRIGHT
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel    40B Oct  1 09:01 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel   159B Oct  1 09:01 README.html
-rwxrwxr-x   1 root  wheel   108K Sep 22 22:49 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel   173K Oct  1 09:01 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
drwxrwxr-x  46 root  wheel   1.5K Oct  1 09:04 bin
drwxrwxr-x   9 root  wheel   306B Oct  1 09:00 db
drwxrwxr-x   9 root  wheel   306B Oct  1 09:00 include
-rwxrwxr-x   1 root  wheel   4.9M Sep 22 22:49 javafx-src.zip
drwxrwxr-x  10 root  wheel   340B Oct  1 09:02 jre
drwxrwxr-x  14 root  wheel   476B Oct  1 09:02 lib
drwxrwxr-x   5 root  wheel   170B Oct  1 09:01 man
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel   529B Oct  1 09:01 release
-rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel    20M Oct  1 09:01 src.zip
```

So, try to set valid path to JDK root directory. I think it should fix your problem.

Comment: Ah..yes mine is supposed to be /usr/java/jdk1.8.0...Thanks...it is working Now.